# Why doesn't momentum eigenstates and wavevector eigenstates have the same form in position representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let $|k'\rangle$ and $|p'\rangle$ be eigenstates of the operator $k$ and $p$ with corresponding eigenvalue $k'$ and $p'$, where $k$ and $p$ represent wavevector and momentum  operators.

Since $k$ and $p$ commute, then they have the common set of simultaneous eigenvectors. It's easy to verify that both {$|k'\rangle$} and {$|p'\rangle$ are eigenstates of either operator $p$ or $k$. So we can write both of the sets as :{$|p',k'\rangle$}.

However there must be a logic flaw here, if this is true, then this means that $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ is the same as $\langle x'|p'\rangle$ in position representation because they can be both written as  $$\langle x'|p',k'\rangle$$

But  $\langle x'|k'\rangle$  is:

[image]

$\langle x'|p'\rangle$ is:

[image]

Why they are differ by a $\sqrt{\hbar}$ in the coefficient? (note the picture for  $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ is 3D case, but for $\langle x'|p'\rangle$ it's 1D case. For simplicity, let's talk about 1D case.
PS: I can derive $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ and $\langle x'|p'\rangle$, it is easy to get the normalization factors, but I what I want to ask is why the logic I used above is wrong?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is? $\mathbf p = \hbar \mathbf k$, which entails an extra factor of $1/\sqrt{\hbar}$ in the normalizing factor.

Comment: @HantingZhang Yes, if my logic is correct, then they should have the same coefficients, right? But I don't know why my logic is wrong, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because the wavefunction is normalized to the Dirac delta, and when you define the normalization integral in the 2 cases:

$$\langle x|x’\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \psi_p^*(x)\psi_p(x’)=\delta(x-x’)$$

Or

$$\langle x|x’\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dk \psi_k^*(x)\psi_k(x’)= \delta(x-x’) $$

You have an additional factor of $\hbar$ coming from $dp=\hbar dk$ to get rid of;

The reason of the different constant is due to the fact that the identity operator can be built both with $\hat k$ and with $\hat p$ eigenstates:

$$\mathbb I=\int dp |p\rangle\langle p|$$

$$\mathbb I=\int dk |k\rangle\langle k|$$

So if we keep symmetry in the definition of the identity operator, we must have asymmetry in the definitions of $\langle p|x\rangle\equiv\psi_p(x)$ and $\langle k|x\rangle\equiv\psi_k(x) $;

Comment: If $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ is the same as $\langle x'|p'\rangle$ in position representation, this entails that in your expression $\psi_p$=$\psi_k$, right? This is why I am concused.

Comment: @UniverseMaintainer  $\langle x'\vert k'\rangle$ is not same as $\langle x'\vert p'\rangle$ since $k'$ and $p'$ differ by a factor of $\hbar$

Comment: Not exactly, I’ll add a further comment on my answer so at least LateX will be visible

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I was answering to Universe Maintainer

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I understand what you mean. How can you tell they are different states? I mean they should be the same be cause I can choose them to be simultaneous eigenstates.

Comment: @UniverseMaintainer they don’t need to be “the same”, it’s ok even if they are proportional to each other

Comment: Namely, if a vector v is eigenvector of an operator M, also $\alpha$v with $\alpha$ any constant different from 0, is eigenvector of M with same eigenvalue;

Comment: in other words, no matter if $\langle p|x\rangle$ and $\langle k|x\rangle$ differ by a multiplicative constant, $|k\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ will still be simultaneous eigenvectors of $\hat k$ and $\hat p$

Comment: Maybe I am stupid...I understand what you said, but I am still very confused. If $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $k$, it must be an eigenstate of $p$ with eigenvalue $p'$,right? So I can name $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ as $$\langle x'|p',k'\rangle$$. Then, this means in your formula,$\psi_k$ and $\psi_p$ should be the same...

Comment: I think the part that you're missing, is that $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $k$ ***no matter*** what constant you put in front of it. You may choose your normalization dividing by ${\sqrt\hbar}$, by $\sqrt{Gc^2\hbar^3}$ or by nothing, but if you apply the differential operator $k\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ you get a number times $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ itself;

Comment: To be even clearer, you cannot fix the normalization from the sole knowledge that $\langle x'|k\rangle$ is eigenvector of this or that operator, you need a further condition which is the normalization of the $|x'\rangle$ vectors, the (in)famous Dirac delta that we were mentioning in both our answers;

Comment: Said that, you do not have to stick literally to the notation you have used, namely $\langle k,p|x'\rangle$: indeed, although you can label a state with more than one letter, to make clear that the state is eigenstate of multiple operators, you have to keep in mind that the family of states $\{|k,p\rangle\}$ still spans ***only one*** Hilbert space, which is the same space spanned by $\{|p\rangle\}$ or $\{|k\rangle\}$. So, even if you write $\{|k,p\rangle\}$, at some point you have to decide which is your "fundamental" eigenvalue, $k$, or $p$, and define your normalization accordingly;

Comment: @FrancescoBernardini Thank you so much for your explanation! Now I get what you mean. I actually made a mistake at the beginning: Having the same set of simultaneous eigenvectors doesn't mean they are the same. Ok, now I have a new question, let's consider the hydrogen atom state: $|E, l, m\rangle$. How could this eigenvectors be normalized? There is not much difference between $|E, l, m\rangle$ and $|k,p\rangle$ state.

Comment: @FrancescoBernardini Maybe the difference is that $k$ and $p$ basis are parallel, whereas in the hydrogen atom the basis is not...

Comment: Yes, in that case you have the dependency on different eigenvalues $n,l,m$ unevenly distributed between the radial part and the spherical harmonic part of the wavefunction; this will affect the form of the normalization integral, but it’s fair to say that the $m$ eigenvalue, for example, has nothing to do with the radial component of the w.f.; in the other case, you can’t factor out $k$ and $p$ dependency in unrelated and factored portions of the w.f., they simply relate to the ***full*** w.f. in the same way (mainly because the two operators are proportional).

Answer (score 0):

In 3 dimensions (with $\hbar = \hbar$), it is the case that

$$\langle \mathbf{r} | \mathbf{p} \rangle = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi \hbar})^3} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{r}/\hbar} $$

Next recall that $\langle \mathbf{r} | \mathbf{p} \rangle^* = \langle \mathbf{p} | \mathbf{r} \rangle$, and so

$$\langle \mathbf{p} | \mathbf{r}\rangle = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi \hbar})^3} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{r}/\hbar}. $$

---

**Derivation**: I will do it for the 1D case.

$$\langle x| \hat{p} | p \rangle = p \langle x | p \rangle \tag{1}$$

Next, the definition of the momentum operator as the generator of translations is given by

$$ {\hat {p}} =i\hbar \lim _{\delta x \rightarrow 0}{\frac {{\hat {T}}(\delta x\mathbf {\hat {x}} )-{\hat {\mathbb {I} }}}{\delta x}} $$

where $\hat{T}$ is the translation operator. Therefore, since $\hat{p}$ is hermitian we can just apply it to $\langle x |$.

$$\langle x| \hat{p} = i\hbar \lim_{\delta x \to 0}\frac{ \langle x + \delta x| - \langle{x}|}{\delta x} $$

plugging this into (1) we have that

$$i\hbar \lim_{\delta x \to 0}\frac{ \langle x + \delta x|p\rangle - \langle{x}|p\rangle}{\delta x}  = i\hbar \frac{d}{dx} \langle{x}| p\rangle = p \langle x | p \rangle $$

That is, we have the differential equation

$$ 
i\hbar \frac{d}{dx} \langle{x}| p\rangle = p \langle x | p \rangle
$$

This is precisely solved by

$$ \langle x | p \rangle = C e^{-i x p /\hbar} $$

for some constant $C$.

Comment: the denominator for $\langle x'|k'\rangle$ indeed don't have $\hbar$ in any source. How do you derive the expression?

Comment: I didn't know you wanted a derivation. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @UniverseMaintainer alright, I added the derivation.

Comment: In your previous answer, does your k state refer to wavevector or momentum state? If it refers to wavevector, the dimension in the exp in not correct.

Comment: You're right. I was referring to wave vector. I'll fix it.

Comment: If your $k$ is a wavevector, $\frac {kr}\hbar$ is dimensionally incorrect as it should be adimensional

Comment: Alright I've fixed it. Forgive me as I have been working in natural units for far too long.

Comment: What’s the normalization of that wavefunction you wrote at the beginning? If you integrate for k (wavevector) going from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ you get $\frac1\hbar\delta(x-x’) $ which is kind of odd

Comment: That's right.. they are delta function normalizable

Comment: yes the delta is right... it's the $\frac1\hbar$ factor that's odd :)

Comment: Okay I will just put it in momentum so that way I know the normalization works